# How to catch if xmlReader property value is empty?

Tags: php, xmlreader

How can I catch if the property value is empty in xmlReader class?
i have tried `$reader->value == ''` and `empty($reader->value)` but it doesn't worked.

This is how look my code:

```
  while ($reader->read()) {
        if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) { 
          $name = $reader->name;
        }

    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT || $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::CDATA){
      switch ($name) {

          case 'zdjecie':

              if (empty($reader->value) || !isset($reader->value)) {
                $zdj = explode('\\',$reader->value);
                $zdjName = end($zdj);
              }else{
                $zdjName = 'no_photo';
              }
            break;
        }
    }

    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'produkt'){

      $reader->next();
      $i++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: empty($reader->value) should work .. what is it you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Use [`XMLReader::getAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.getattribute.php) for reading an attribute; the docs does not mention you can use the properties to access attributes.</del>

Looking your code, `empty($reader->value) || !isset($reader->value)` is redundant. `isset` will only check against `null`, while `empty` will return `true` on empty strings **too** (as `value` is always defined on `XMLReader`).

You can use `empty($reader->value)` or `!$reader->value` as condition, but you switched the cases.

```
if (empty($reader->value)) { // or simply: !$reader->value
    $zdjName = 'no_photo';
} else {
    $zdj = explode('\\',$reader->value);
    $zdjName = end($zdj);
}
```

`+` Hint: You should be aware, that in XML, white-spaces considered to be part of the node's value.

Comment: In case 'zdjecie' I need to try if the value of this node is empty. It is not attrubute. But when i try `$reader->value == ''` the statment *if* return false even if the node is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `isset()`,

```
if(empty($reader->value) || !isset($reader->value)){

}
```